# Generics - get value from Class<T>

Tags: java, generics, jpa, reflection

I've a class that converts my jpa entities into TO and vice versa.

When i do the conversion in the method `convertEntityListInTOList`, the `List` returned is `List<Class<T>>` and i need that be `List<T>`.

Is possible iterate over this collection (`List<Class<T>>`) and get the "TO" value?

Converter

```
    public class MyConverter<E, T> implements Serializable {

        private Class<E> myEntity;
        private Class<T> myTO;

        public MyConverter(Class<E> myEntity, Class<T> myTO) {
            this.myEntity = myEntity;
            this.myTO = myTO;
        }

        public List<T> convertEntityListInTOList(List<E> entityList) {
            List<T> listTO = new ArrayList<T>();
            for(E obj : entityList) {
                myTO = convertEntityInTO(obj);
                listTO.add(myTO);
            }               
            return listTO;
        }

        public List<E> convertTOListInEntityList(List<T> listTOs) {
            List<E> entityList = new ArrayList<E>();
            for(T to : listTOs) {
                myEntity = convertTOInEntity(to);
                entityList.add(myEntity);
            }           
            return entityList;
        }

        public T convertEntityInTO(Object myEntity) {
            T myTO = createInstanceTO();
            if(myEntity != null) {
                try {
                    BeanUtils.copyProperties(myTO, myEntity);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return myTO;
        }

        public E convertTOInEntity(T myTO) {
            E myEntity = createInstanceEntity();
            if(myTO != null) {
                try {
                    BeanUtils.copyProperties(myEntity, myTO);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }    
            return myEntity;    
        }

/**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public T createInstanceTO() {
        try {
            return getMyTO().newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public E createInstanceEntity() {
        try {
            return getMyEntity().newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Converter producer

```
@Produces
public MyConverter create(InjectionPoint ip) {
    ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) ip.getType();
    Class myEntity = (Class) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    Class myTO = (Class) type.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    return new MyConverter(myEntity, myTO);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you're getting back `List<Class<T>>`? Is there an error message? Stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for reply. This list is send to a jsf page (xhtml). An error message is displayed: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: ..."#{item.image}": Property 'image' not found on type java.lang.Class

'image' is MyTO's attribute

Comment: How do you expect to get help without showing the jsf page as well? What is `item`?

Comment: I edited the original message by adding the requested files.
The files were not added because it works when I'm not using the generic converter. If I populate the list of objects (MyTo) without conversion to the generic list is displayed normally.

Comment: If you're getting `List<Class<T>>` then how do you anticipate getting the _values_ within the instances of type `T`? It's easy to loop across a list of `Class`es and instantiate them (`type.newInstance();`), but I think you need to look at this differently. You need to get the actual instances with their values rather than types that need to be filled in. Having just the class suggests you aren't getting the right thing to begin with.

Comment: Problem solved. The error was in the class to convert. The original message has been edited with correction. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of problems with your code. You’re mixing objects (for example, an object of type `MyEntity`) and objects that represent the class of those objects (for example `Class<MyEntity>`).

So, when you write

```
Class myEntity = (Class) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    Class myTO = (Class) type.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    return new MyConverter(myEntity, myTO);
```

you’re trying to create a converter that converts a `Class` into another `Class`, which doesn’t make sense. That’s why the return type of `convertEntityListInTOList` is a list of class.

Creating a converter containing one instance of each entities doesn't make sens either. You should rather create a new instance each time, or populate an instance given as a parameter to the convert method.